# TestNG- No tests found. Nothing was run

Tags: testng, api-testing, maven, rest-assured, api-automation

UTF-8
  
  
        
            io.rest-assured
            rest-assured
            4.1.2
            test
        
        
        
            org.testng
            testng
            6.14.3
        
**************************************************
TestNg.xml

[image]

Comment: Show us your pom.xml

Comment: <dependency>
   <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
   <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
   <version>4.1.2</version>
   <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>



  <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.testng/testng -->
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
   <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
   <version>6.14.3</version>
  </dependency>
  
  
  <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.scribejava</groupId>
            <artifactId>scribejava-apis</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

Comment: <version>6.14.3</version>

TestNg Version

Comment: Just put your pom to your question. not to comments. Including plugins section.

Comment: Added my POM in ques

Comment: @AshutoshSingh Also it will be good if you post the `testng.xml`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

make sure you are importing `org.testng.annotations.Test` and not `org.junit.Test`

Answer (score 0):

This error message implies that **TestNG** didn't find any `@Test` to execute.

```
[TestNG] No tests found. Nothing was run
```

Make sure you have imported `Test` annotation & used `@Test` to execute.

```
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
```

Comment: I have imported the correct dependecy

import static io.restassured.RestAssured.*;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.*;

**import org.testng.annotations.Test;**

import io.restassured.RestAssured;
import io.restassured.response.Response;
import io.restassured.specification.RequestSpecification;

Comment: Are you using the @Test annotation in the script to execute test?

Comment: Yes,  @Test
 public void getAPITest() {

Comment: Share the code snippet .... are you using annotation in the main method?

Comment: because the main method does not take any annotation. If you provide any TestNG annotation to the main method then you will get the same error.

Comment: I have pasted entire code in below location:-

https://gist.github.com/asingh4305/4d86c9e3a653149e7c0d31a4411e19a6

Comment: @AshutoshSingh Please share your `testng.xml`

Comment: https://gist.github.com/asingh4305/357942114e64dfa0dedbf9e44debd4f5

**Please find the TestNg.xml in the given location**

Comment: @AshutoshSingh refer to updated answer

Comment: Hi All, Thanks for helping me here. I am able to run all my TestNg.xml file using below code. You may refer below github link 

https://gist.github.com/asingh403/3e4b4644431af98feb75804bb84cb2a9

Answer (score 0):

As per your code reference [testng.xml](https://gist.github.com/asingh4305/357942114e64dfa0dedbf9e44debd4f5) and your [test](https://gist.github.com/asingh4305/4d86c9e3a653149e7c0d31a4411e19a6) class there is no method `getTestNgTest1` inside the class `com.rest.api.authentications.OAuth2APITest`

Change the `testng.xml` to the below one probably it will work

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
    <suite guice-stage="DEVELOPMENT" name="Default suite">
      <test thread-count="5" verbose="2" name="Default test">
        <classes>
          <class name="com.rest.api.authentications.OAuth2APITest" />
        </classes>
      </test> <!-- Default test -->
    </suite> <!-- Default suite -->
```

Comment: Updated TestNg.xml but no Luck Still same issue .

Comment: @AshutoshSingh I made a run from my local machine with your sample code and my updated `testng.xml` works fine for me. Try by adding `scope` to your testng dependency in `pom.xml` file and atlast make restart to your IDE. Make cross verify whether the dependencies are loaded to your project from POM file not from the Jar file in buildpath which you may have added unknowingly

Comment: I have added and follow the instruction but still not working 
**pom.xml link**

https://gist.github.com/asingh4305/4870d1cd56b6112495255934306000cd

Answer (score 0):

Your `pom.xml` has to include `maven surefire` plugin inside `<build>...</build>` tags:

```
<properties>
...
</properties>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.19.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <suiteXmlFiles>
                    <suiteXmlFile>src/test/testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                </suiteXmlFiles>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<dependencies>
...
</dependencies>
```

Then you can execute your tests by running `mvn test`.
Bare in mind it will pick up every class that has a `...test` suffix and look for methods annotated with `@Test` only in such classes.

How to execute a single test (question in comments):
You can provide method name in `testng.xml` file, like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="testSuite" verbose="1">
    <test name="tests">
        <classes>
            <class name="className">
                <methods>
                    <include name="testMethodName"></include>
                </methods>
            </class>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

Or simply run it via maven:

```
mvn test -Dtest=className#methodName
```

When executing a single test via maven, you might need to add `-DfailIfNoTests=false` so that maven does not fail, when multiple modules exist.

Comment: Correct i want to run only single test at a time... Not entire build

Comment: I have updated my answer with information on running a single test.

Comment: mvn test -Dtest=className#methodName


Its worked ..thanks

Comment: If my answer helped you, please mark it as solved, so that others can use it as reference.